# What server and login must I enter to connect to a SQL Server that was installed together with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I am just learn C# from Java and now struggling with sql server

i usually use mysql with phpmyadmin

i use windows 7

i already install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, in control panel *program and feature* there is some name with sql server

i try to search the answer in google for 3 days & download many youtube tutorial. but still confuse what to do.

**My goal :**

i try to create ms sql database like i do in phpmyadmin

i dont want to create local database, i try to create database in server (the server sit in localhost)

**heres what i do :**

- in visual studio 2013 - server explorer tab, i right click in data
  connections
- then select *Create New Sql Server Database*

dialog show up and **my question :**

1. What value i must put in *Server Name*
2. If i select radio button *Use SQL Server Authentication*. what value i
   must put in *username* and *password*. (when installing visual
   studio, it don't tell me anything)

thank, forgive my english

**EDIT :**

i already install management studio from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx). At installing, it dont tell me any configuration.

Using SSMS i still can't create database, i already try :

- via *Windows Authentication* with servername : 127.0.0.1 or localhost
- via SQL Server Authentication with *username* : sa, *password* :
  [empty], or Password123, or [myComputerPassword]

i already try uninstall & install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition & SQL Server 2014 Management Studio multiple time in different PC. But it dont tell me any configuration when installing.

based on my newbie feeling : (maybe) it look like installation don't create instance server

here's my control panel look like : [image: screenshot]

Comment: Try `.` as servername
`sa` as user
blank as password
or use Windows authentication

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri already try 3 time but still not work, under control panel it looks like i use between sql server 2012 or sql server 2014

Comment: can you connect to SSMS? can you try `select @@version`?
if it is 2014 SQL, then you can not do this with studio. Only versions of SQL up to 2012 are supported. And why not to create database through SSMS itself?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i dont have SSMS. i will try install it first and tell the result

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i already install SSMS sir. But still can't create database. i edit my question to show some details. in cmd i try select @@version but it do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless SQL Server was installed with non-default settings, the following connection parameters should allow you to connect to your (locally installed) SQL Server instance:

- **Password:** chances are that SQL Server was installed with SQL Server authentication disabled. Try to log in with the option *Integrated Authentication* or *Integrated Security* enabled, then you won't even have the option to enter a username and password.
- **Server:** try these in the following order:

  - `.\SQLEXPRESS` (which stands for "instance named `SQLEXPRESS` on the local host, `.`")
  - `.` (which stands for "(instance with default name on the) local host")
  - `(localdb)`

  Basically, the server name consists of up to three parts: First, the network host on which the desired SQL Server service is running (the local host or `.` in your case), the name of the SQL Server service after a `\` (often `MSSQLSERVER` or `SQLSERVER`, the first of which you can omit because it's the default name), and a network port on which the SQL Server service is listening (you can often omit that, too).

  You can find out your SQL Server's service name from *Administrative Tools* → *Services*. Locate the entry for the *SQL Server* service and note down the name in the parentheses; that's what will go after the `.\` in the server name:

  [image: SQL Server service name is mentioned in Services]

Answer (score 1):

You usually get a local or express version of Sql Server installed when you install Visual Studio.

You can however..go a little further.

Sql Server Express 2014 (You may already have this installed based on what you chose during the install)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx

Sql Server 2012 Express

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Under the 2012, you'll also note that one of the downloads is

SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

This is "Sql Server Management Studio".  This is a front-end to the Sql Server RDBMS.  You could do most things through Visual Studio, but I usually install SSMS as well.  SSMS is kinda the same thing as MySql Workbench.
You can also write scripts and execute them in SSMS.

You security mode is probably "Trusted" which means you connect to Sql Server using your windows credentials.  This was auto-voodoo'ed mapped for you when you did the install.

Sql Authentication (the alternative to Trusted) is the username/password model.  This takes extra setup and configuration (usually through SSMS), so your easiest bet is to rely on "Trusted" unless you find a need for something else.

I hope that helps.

Comment: i already try using SqlAuthentication & Windows Authentication but i still cant create database. i edit my question to show some details